# Grep find string that is not followed by a charater

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I have a parameter `params` and I need two variables – one for words from `params` that contain `=` and another with words that don't have an `=` in them.

```
params="step1 step2 step3 param1=1 param2=2 param3=3"

test=$(grep -o '\b\w*\=\b\w*' <<<$params)
echo -e "test: " $test
```

this works and it gives me :

```
param1=1 param2=2 param3=3
```

But the negation part is not working.
If I have to use grep -o, How to make this work?

These did not work so far

```
$(grep -o '\b\w*[^\=]*' <<<$params)
$(grep -o '\b\w*[^\=]\b\w*' <<<$params)
```

I need this as the answer :

```
step1 step2 step3
```

Comment: @Jasen I don't think that will work as expected with `-o`

Comment: fair enough,  - I guess the question then is what do the words User wants to find look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` isn't suited to this. If you *must* use it, the following will work:

```bsh
grep -Fv = <<<$(printf '%s\n' $params)
```

and if you *must* use `grep -o`:

```bsh
grep -o '^[^=]*$' <<<$(printf '%s\n' $params)
```

- the above uses `bash` to print `words` from `params`, each on their own line, that way `grep` is much easier to use (definition of `words` will depend on the value of `IFS`)

---

`awk` might be better:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "} !/=/' <<<"$params"
```

or:

```bsh
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i !~ /=/) print $i}' <<<"$params"
```

---

`bash` could achieve this on it's own with an array parameter:

```bsh
paramsarray=( $params )
echo "${paramsarray[@]/*=*}"
```

Comment: Thanks!! awk defenitely seems better.